# deactivate or undo webshims polyfill to use my own instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, polyfills, webshim

In my webform CMS I habitually polyfill all form elements that are not supported using Webshim.

This strategy led to some trouble, because I want to use my own polyfill for a number input that is already being polyfilled by Webshim in some browsers (e.g. FF 28).

I cannot wrap my head around what I would have to do to prevent Webshim polyfilling that element or what to do to undo the polyfill, or at least it seems as if I'm doing it the wrong way.

I would prefer undoing the polyfill because that's my current use case, but when I call `.getShadowElement()` on my input, I cannot use `.hide()` and I would also have to do some extra legwork to hide the spin buttons.

To my mind, it should be sufficient that I am calling `webshim.addShadowDom()` after adding my substitute, since the newer shadowdom should supercede the old, but that does not happen.

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWW9H/8/) showing the furthest I got.

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? Do you want to add a different UI for all browsers? Or do you want to add only a polyfill to browsers, which do not support type="number"?

Comment: + Can you describe the UI (style and behavior) of your polyfill or your UI replacement?

Comment: This might be a better start: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/zWW9H/15/ In case you give me more information. I can improve this.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas Thanks for the help! I misused the word "polyfill", I intend to use just +/- buttons in all browsers, but I want to fall back to a numeric input in case of no JS. Your solution is fine, I didn't go the CSS route because I thought you had made polyfill styles hard to override on purpose. Later last night I solved it by wrapping the input in a span and hiding that. But there's no general way I suppose?

Comment: I will try to answer this later, but here is some code to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/75AFk/ . Note: I made some small changes to webshim to get this support better, you need version 1.14.5-pre

Comment: @alexanderfarkas `ws-nopolyfill` is the level of simplicity I was hoping for :-) Thanks. And – of course any other day I love to use your polyfills ;-)